# How to check if Chrome window is focused?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, service-worker

I am developing notifications using the Push API with service workers. I'm currently doing something like this so that I only display the notification if the user is not already tabbed into the site:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll().then(function(clientList) {
    for (let i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
      if (clientList[i].visibilityState === "visible") { // if any window is visible, don't send a notification
        return;
      }
    }

    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification("Notification"));
  })
}
```

This works alright, except for the fact that if the user is tabbed into my site, but tabbed out of their browser, then it doesn't work. I'll make a table:

```
user is tabbed into site                            notification not sent    CORRECT
user is not tabbed into site                        notification is sent     CORRECT
user is not tabbed into site or browser             notification is sent     CORRECT
user is tabbed into site but tabbed out of browser  notification not sent    INCORRECT
```

Is it possible to fix the last case? I want the notification to send in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Would [visibilitychange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event) event work for you?

You can add it to your plain javascript files, and then send post message to service worker when the visibility changes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
        if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
            console.log('IS VISIBLE');
        } else {
            console.log('NOT VISIBLE');
            let meg = {...some message object}
            swRegistration.active.postMessage(msg);
        }
    });

</script>
```